# Jams Scheduler Client 7.1.478.0- Shortcut bar has disappeared

Tags: debugging, windows-10, software-design

The title says it all. I use Jams Scheduler on a daily basis. The Shortcut menu, which is a default feature of the program and gives me access to job history and monitoring, is simply not on the front page when I open the program. I have tried altering font size and scaling options on Windows 10. The jams scheduler guide doesn't offer any help since every direction they have starts with "go to the shortcut bar". Please see the highlighted portion of the screenshot to see the portion that is missing. Has anyone run into this problem before?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

JAMS has an option to make the Shortcuts panel float in a separate window by right-clicking on the Shortcuts panel title bar and selecting Float, or by dragging the shortcuts title bar out of the JAMS window. My guess is that your Shortcuts window is floating off screen.

You can restore your JAMS client back to defaults by deleting the version subfolder underneath your user's AppData Local folder for JAMS. By default, this folder is under C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\HelpSystems\JAMS. Delete the 7.1.478.0 folder and the next time you open JAMS it will treat you as a new user with default views and a restored Shortcuts bar. This means you'll need to re-enter your server name, so if you don't remember it, make sure before you delete the folder you hit the gears icon and select "Servers..." to see your server name.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the previous answer - if you don't want to loose the servers and re-enter them again, you can:

1. back up your servers.xml file
2. Delete the folder as suggested by Rob Grafrath
3. Run Jams Client - you should see the shortcuts panel and the folder that you deleted will reappear
4. Close the Jams Client and paste the server.xml into the newly generated folder.
   Or you can back up the entire folder and paste all XML files to the newly generated folder.